# Initialized Replication Subscriber from Backup with @allow_anonymous,@immediate_sync off

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2014, transactional-replication

I have initialized Replication Subscriber from Backup with @allow_anonymous,@immediate_sync = flase
It is working good.
Do I need t o change the setting back to true or just leave with false.